# MonoTouch localized xibs/nibs not placed in bundle correctly

Tags: localization, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xib

I am trying to localize the xib files in my MonoTouch app. I have them included in the project and the build action is set to page. When I run it random things are in a different language.

Looking at the resulting app bundle all of the nib files are at the root. I'm guessing that whichever xib gets processed last is the one that wins. Looking at a localized app built by Xcode the nib files are separated out into en-US.lproj, fr-CA.lproj, etc...

I've searched around for help on this and surprisingly can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the lproj folders in your project, and place the localized xibs in those.